# Array Index Out of Bound Exception - Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, indexoutofboundsexception

I want to print a two dimensional matrix in Scala and I keep getting Array Index Out of Bound Exception.
I have used breakable code and still I am encountering the issue.

```
package com.edureka.scala
import scala.util.control.Breaks._

class Pascal 
{
  val r,c=0
  val matrix=Array.ofDim[Int](r,c) //declare a two-dimensional array
    def fun
      {
       breakable
         {
           for(r <- 0 until 4 ;c <- 0 until 4)
            {
               println(matrix(r)(c)=r+c)
               if(r>3)break
            }
          }
      }
}

object pas1 extends App
{

  val pasobj=new Pascal()
  pasobj.fun

}
```

Comment: There is no reason to declare variables, like `r` and `c`, to use them in a for-loop.  This makes it harder for another Scala programmer to read this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an empty array:

```
val matrix = Array.ofDim[Int](0, 0)
matrix: Array[Array[Int]] = Array()
```

Since there are no entries, retrieving one fails:

```
scala> matrix(0)(0)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

And assigning to one fails, as well:

```
scala> matrix(0)(0) = 0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

You need to declare an array of 4x4 dimension:

```
val matrix = Array.ofDim[Int](4, 4)
matrix: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 0, 0, 0), Array(0, 0, 0, 0),  ...)
```

Then you can assign successfully:

```
scala> matrix(3)(3) = 3
```

And retrieve as well:

```
scala> matrix(3)(3)
res1: Int = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You define an *empty* array of array of ints, since you declare `r,c=0`

```
@ val m = Array.ofDim[Int](0, 0) 
m: Array[Array[Int]] = Array()
```

And then in your loop you try to access the elements in that array (which do not exist)

```
@ m(0)(0) 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
  $sess.cmd5$.<init>(cmd5.sc:1)
  $sess.cmd5$.<clinit>(cmd5.sc:-1)
```

Simply creating an array of arrays does not fill it with values, especially when you set its dimensions as `0`. You can set the dimensions higher and you will have a populated array:

```
@ val m2 = Array.ofDim[Int](5, 5) 
m2: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(
  Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
)
@ m2(1)(4) 
res7: Int = 0
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using for-comprehensions in Scala http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/sequence-comprehensions.html

Comment: You're absolutely right, and it isn't my place to police others' practices